# Stream Read Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: windows-services, serversocket

I am working on a windows service to communicate with servers, In which I am using the [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-6.0) class.

In TcpListener class, after 3 successful socket connections, the 4th connection is returning an error.

```
class MyTcpListener
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    TcpListener server=null;
    try
    {
      // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
      Int32 port = 13000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // Buffer for reading data
      Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
      String data = null;

      // Enter the listening loop.
      while(true)
      {
        Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

        // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
        // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

        data = null;

        // Get a stream object for reading and writing
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        int i;

        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
        while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0)
        {
          // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
          data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
          Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

          // Process the data sent by the client.
          data = data.ToUpper();

          byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

          // Send back a response.
          stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
          Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
        }

        // Shutdown and end connection
        client.Close();
      }
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();
  }
}
```

On this line on the 4th connection, it's returning an error.

`// Send back a response.`
`stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);`

**Error:**

> Stream Write Error: Unable to write data to the transport connection:
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Stream
> Write Error:   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)